# Not able to pass the two parameters in url

Tags: python, django

I defined a function and am trying to pass two parameters in the URL.

When run it shows the error `"not enough arguments for format string"`

Here is the code
**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def detail(request, question_id,choice):
    response="You're looking at question %s and choice %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id , choice)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url( r'^$', views.index , name='index' ) ,
    url( r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9])/(?P<choice>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail , name='detail' ) ,
]
```

When i pass the url

http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/2/

**Error**

```
TypeError at /polls/1/2/
not enough arguments for format string
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%` is the old way of formatting strings in python. It's better to use `.format(..)` such as

```
response = "You're looking at question {} and choice {}.".format(question_id, choice)
```

So your code will be

```
def detail(request, question_id,choice):
    response = "You're looking at question {} and choice {}.".format(question_id, choice)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Have a look at [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/) for more information.

Comment: when use  this along with the like

def detail ( request , question_id , choice ): response = "You're looking at question {} and choice {}.".format(question_id , choice )
return HttpResponse (response % (question_id , choice) )

the error raises says
"not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: Sorry, the use of `format` is in place of the use of `%`. I've updated my answer to show the full example.

Comment: When any solution fulfill your requirement, you should accept it as your selected answer by ticking the checkmark next to the answer @Ishaan Gupta. This is how you can show you gratitude and give credit to the owner of that answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return HttpResponse(response % (question_id, choice))`